# Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package. Requests of the current directory need to start with './'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, directory, clone, modulenotfounderror

Here is the code for **Home** page in the *components* folder

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import ImageSlider from './ImageSlider'
import Viewers from './Viewers'
import Movies from './Movies'
import db from '../firebase'

function Home() {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello");
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <ImageSlider />   
      <Viewers />
      <Movies />   
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Home

const Container = styled.main`
    min-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    padding: 0 calc(3.5vw + 5px);
    position: relatiive;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    &:before{
      background: url("/images/home-background.png") center center/cover no-repeat fixed; 
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: -1; 
    }
`
```

---

Here is the code for the **firebase.js** in the *src* folder

```js
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA9BnlX96fMf7XiUVCFRsoQzG8DGERJkeY",
  authDomain: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5",
  storageBucket: "disneyplus-clone-a33d5.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "37918794208",
  appId: "1:37918794208:web:dbe9842dfe1dda522a4b85",
  measurementId: "G-DRVLJKWRWG",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { auth, provider, storage };
export default db;
```

---

Here is a screenshot of all the folders of the project disney-plus-clone

[All Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORRhW.jpg)

When I am trying to import the firebase.js component in my Home.js the following error is displayed:

Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 3:0-32
Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package D:\Web Development\disney-plus-clone\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in D:\Web Development\disney-plus-clone\node_modules\firebase\package.json)
Did you mean './firebase'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, D:\Web Development\disney-plus-clone\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

[Error Message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm5NU.jpg)

I am new to React JS. If anyone is able to solve this error please leave a solution to this.

---

1. I have tried using the following code snippet in the Home.js component:

`import db from '../firebase'`

But this code snippet was showing the above error(Error Message 1).

2. I have tried using the following code snippet in the Home.js component:

`import db from './firebase'`

But this was showing the following error:

[Error Message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSlMd.jpg)

3. I have tried using the following code snippet in the Home.js component:

`import db from './src/firebase'`

But the following error was occurring:

[Error Message 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlCIf.jpg)